# Convert / decode numpy array of byte8 characters to string

Tags: python, string, numpy, decode

I'm having trouble converting a numpy array of type bytes8 into a string. I guess I need to decode the data but I'm not sure how to do this for a numpy array. The array is of size [1200,8] but the data is repeated along the largest dimension so I only really need to convert one row to a string.

The first entry of the array gives the following output on the command line:
array([b'5', b'5', b'5', b'7', b'0', b' ', b' ', b' '], 
      dtype='|S1')

I have tried things like .tostring() but with no luck. The issue seems to be that the object is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension including `encoding="utf-8"`, otherwise the `b` will still remain in the list.

```
array = [str(s, encoding='UTF-8') for s in array]
```

returns

```
['5', '5', '5', '7', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

if you then wish to make a complete string you can do

```
''.join(array)
```

which will return the string

```
55570
```

You can achieve the same using only one line and parenthesis which will create a `generator object`.

A generator object will not create a list in memory so it will be faster.

```
array = ''.join(str(s, encoding='UTF-8') for s in array)
```